# Hide button in each detail row

Tags: jquery, closest

I have a drill down list that contains a button in each row. How can I hide these buttons using jQuery?

I have tried the following code but I was not able to find the button.

```js
$(".s_invoicedtl").closest(".card").find(".btn-default")
```

Here is the HTML of one of the rows containing the button -

```html
<tr class="ew-table-preview-row">
  <td class="ew-table-last-col ew-table-last-row" colspan="10">
    <!-- preview -->
    <div class="ew-nav-tabs">
      <!-- .ew-nav-tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" data-table="s_invoicedtl"
            data-url="/s_invoicedtlpreview?t=s_invoice&amp;f=gKD81aAcp3oYWIAnst6HVg" data-target="#131127">s
            invoicedtl&nbsp;<span class="badge badge-info ew-detail-count1">1</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <!-- .tab-content -->
        <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="131127">
          <div class="card ew-grid s_invoicedtl">
            <!-- .card -->
            <div class="table-responsive card-body ew-grid-middle-panel ew-preview-middle-panel">
              <!-- .table-responsive -->
              <table class="table ew-table ew-preview-table">
                <!-- .table -->
                <thead>
                  <!-- Table header -->
                  <tr class="ew-table-header">

                    <th class="ew-table-header-cell">
                      <div class="ew-pointer" data-sort="Id_item_code" data-sort-order="ASC">
                        <div class="ew-table-header-btn">
                          <span class="ew-table-header-caption">Item</span>
                          <span class="ew-table-header-sort"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="ew-table-header-cell">
                      <div class="ew-pointer" data-sort="qty" data-sort-order="ASC">
                        <div class="ew-table-header-btn">
                          <span class="ew-table-header-caption">Qty</span>
                          <span class="ew-table-header-sort"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="ew-table-header-cell">
                      <div class="ew-pointer" data-sort="price_unit" data-sort-order="ASC">
                        <div class="ew-table-header-btn">
                          <span class="ew-table-header-caption">Unit Price</span>
                          <span class="ew-table-header-sort"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="ew-table-header-cell">
                      <div class="ew-pointer" data-sort="Id_uom" data-sort-order="ASC">
                        <div class="ew-table-header-btn">
                          <span class="ew-table-header-caption">Unit</span>
                          <span class="ew-table-header-sort"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="ew-table-header-cell">
                      <div class="ew-pointer" data-sort="Id_taxmaster" data-sort-order="ASC">
                        <div class="ew-table-header-btn">
                          <span class="ew-table-header-caption">Tax</span>
                          <span class="ew-table-header-sort"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="ew-table-header-cell">
                      <div class="ew-pointer" data-sort="tax_rate" data-sort-order="ASC">
                        <div class="ew-table-header-btn">
                          <span class="ew-table-header-caption">TxRate</span>
                          <span class="ew-table-header-sort"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="ew-table-header-cell">
                      <div class="ew-pointer" data-sort="discount" data-sort-order="ASC">
                        <div class="ew-table-header-btn">
                          <span class="ew-table-header-caption">Discount</span>
                          <span class="ew-table-header-sort"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="ew-table-header-cell">
                      <div class="ew-pointer" data-sort="taxamount" data-sort-order="ASC">
                        <div class="ew-table-header-btn">
                          <span class="ew-table-header-caption">Tax</span>
                          <span class="ew-table-header-sort"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="ew-table-header-cell ew-table-last-col">
                      <div class="ew-pointer" data-sort="amount" data-sort-order="ASC">
                        <div class="ew-table-header-btn">
                          <span class="ew-table-header-caption">Amount</span>
                          <span class="ew-table-header-sort"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </th>

                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <!-- Table body -->
                  <tr class="ew-table-row">

                    <td class="ew-table-last-row">
                      <span>SDSCFi1, Stam Duty: Facility Agreement SCF-i.1</span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;" class="ew-table-last-row">
                      <span>5</span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;" class="ew-table-last-row">
                      <span>44,020.00</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="ew-table-last-row">
                      <span>UNIT</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="ew-table-last-row">
                      <span>SRG0 </span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;" class="ew-table-last-row">
                      <span>0.00</span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: justify;" class="ew-table-last-row">
                      <span>0.00</span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;" class="ew-table-last-row">
                      <span>0.00</span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;" class="ew-table-last-col ew-table-last-row">
                      <span>220,100.00</span>
                    </td>

                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table><!-- /.table -->
            </div><!-- /.table-responsive -->
            <div class="card-footer ew-grid-lower-panel ew-preview-lower-panel">
              <!-- .card-footer -->
              <div class="ew-preview-other-options">

              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div><!-- /.card-footer -->
          </div><!-- /.card -->
          <div data-table="s_invoicedtl" data-url="/s_invoicedtlpreview?t=s_invoice&amp;f=gKD81aAcp3oYWIAnst6HVg"
            class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" title=""
              onclick="window.location='/s_invoicedtllist?showmaster=s_invoice&amp;fk_Id=26'"
              data-original-title="s invoicedtl">
              <i data-phrase="MasterDetailListLink" class="icon-table ew-icon" data-caption="Detail List">
              </i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.tab-content -->
    </div><!-- /.ew-nav-tabs -->
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You should upload the HTML here, as part of your [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: apologize for the inconveniences, I have updated my question with sample html code for a row drill down which contains the button. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`.find()` in your attempt wouldn't work because it would searches descending from your selection, when the button was a *sibling* to your selection

Trying to stay similar to how you had originally tried, you can either make use of the [`next sibling selector ~`](https://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) to find the button that is in the same element group as `.s_invoicedt1`, or use `.parent().find()` to move up the DOM before trying to `.find()` your button

```js
let $button = $('.card.s_invoicedtl ~ .btn-group .btn');
// let $button = $('.card.s_invoicedtl').parent().find('.btn-group .btn');

$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log($button.length);
  $button.hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr class="ew-table-preview-row">
    <td class="ew-table-last-col ew-table-last-row" colspan="10">
        <!-- preview -->
        <div class="ew-nav-tabs">
            <!-- .ew-nav-tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs"><li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" data-table="s_invoicedtl" data-url="/s_invoicedtlpreview?t=s_invoice&amp;f=gKD81aAcp3oYWIAnst6HVg" data-target="#131127">s invoicedtl&nbsp;<span class="badge badge-info ew-detail-count1">1</span></a></li></ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <!-- .tab-content -->
                <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="131127">
                    <div class="card ew-grid s_invoicedtl">
                        <!-- Card Content -->
                    </div>
                    <div data-table="s_invoicedtl" data-url="/s_invoicedtlpreview?t=s_invoice&amp;f=gKD81aAcp3oYWIAnst6HVg" class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="demo" onclick="window.location='/s_invoicedtllist?showmaster=s_invoice&amp;fk_Id=26'" data-original-title="s invoicedtl">
                            <i data-phrase="MasterDetailListLink" class="icon-table ew-icon" data-caption="Detail List">
                            </i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.tab-content -->
        </div><!-- /.ew-nav-tabs -->
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to hide the button when it's clicked then you can simply add this to the button:

```
onclick="this.style.display = 'none';"
```

if not, you can use this code to hide it:

```
$('.btn').style.display = 'none';
```

**EDIT:**
You can add a shared class/id for the buttons you want to hide (in this case the class *btn*)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').style.display = 'none';
});
//or if you just want to hide the first button you can use:
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn')[0].style.display = 'none';
});
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
//or if you just want to hide all buttons in the row with the id *Row*:
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Row .btn').style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: No, I wanted to hide those buttons on start up.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide every single buttons with class '.btn-default' on start,

try  something like this.

```
$(function(){
    $('button .btn-default').each(function(){

        $(this).hide(); // or $(this).css("display", "none");  

    });
});
```